# Compute probability of parameters given data in a bayesian network with pyMC3

Tags: python, pymc3, pymc, bayesian-networks, expectation-maximization

I’m new to pyMC3 and I would like to know if it is possible to use it to solve the following problem: I have a bayesian network (image of my BN: [Bayesian network of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpaVh.png)) and I don’t know the parameters of the distributions of A,B,C,D and S, I just know the type of distribution (there are both discrete and continuous distributions). I have data from A,B,C and D (thus S is a hidden variable and it is discrete) and my goal is to determine the probability of S given the observed data. I know that one approach is to use the expectation maximization algorithm but I was wondering if it is possible to solve the problem with pyMC3. Thank you.
Best regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve the problem only when you know how S is related to A, B, C and D.

If as mentioned in the image, S is impacted by all of them equally, you can write

```
S = A + B
```

If we know S is a binary then we can write,

```
S =  1/ (1 + exp(A+ B))
```

Then you can define A, B, C, and D in terms of their distributions. 
pyMC3 will run an MCMC simulation to estimate the parameters of the distribution. 
With the mean of those parameters, you can estimate A, B, C, and D which after addition will give you S.

Comment: But if, for instance, A is binary and B,C and D are normal, how can the sum of their means provide me an estimate for S (S is binary) ?

Comment: Yes, so if it is not simple addition, you would need a weighted sum to say alpha1*A + alpha2*B + ... 
But to estimate alpha1, alpha2, etc you will need some data for S

Comment: Also if you know S is binary then you can even logit on the addition. s= logit(A+B+C+D) Here logit is a deterministic function we know already based on our information about S(being binary)

Comment: Thus in the pyMC model I should declare only A,B,C and D and then, after running an MCMC, compute S distribution with logit?

Comment: Yes.. However now that I see the image again, it appears that,  we didn't consider the direction of arrows. Only A and B should be considered for S calculation. Which again then can be used in parameter estimation of C and D.

Comment: S will be used as an input for C and D estimation.